# Azure Maps Get Map Image Request returns a blank map image

Tags: rest, azure, azure-maps

I'm trying to use the [Azure Get Map Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render/getmapimage) API call. When using the "Try It!" feature in the documentation, I get a status 200 (success). When I put the request in the browser, a blank map is returned.

Request:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=<myApiKey>&api-version=1.0&layer=hybrid&zoom=7&center=-122.3927721%2047.568873&height=800&width=800&language=en&style=main
```

Response:
[image]

Please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your request isn't formatted correctly. The `center` query param needs to have a `,` between the `long` and the `lat` (right now it has a space `%20`).

Try this:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=<myApiKey>&api-version=1.0&layer=hybrid&zoom=7&center=-122.3927721,47.568873&height=800&width=800&language=en&style=main
```

Comment: Thanks you! That did indeed work. Think I'll submit a bug report to Microsoft because the query that is built using the docs (and returns status 200) has all spaces!

https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=<myApiKey>&api-version=1.0&path=%7C%7C-122%2045%7C-119.5%2043.2%7C-121.67%2047.12&layer=hybrid&style=main&zoom=11&center=-119.5%2043.2&height=800&width=800&language=en

Comment: Hm. Working with this a little more. I added a `path` parameter (after upping my Azure Subscription to an S1) and I'm getting the same blank map as before. I was sure to add "," instead of " " between the path parameters. 

GET https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=<myApiKey>&api-version=1.0&path=%7C-122%2C45%7C-119.5%2C43.2%7C-121.67%2C47.12&layer=hybrid&style=main&zoom=11&center=-119.5%2C43.2&height=800&width=800&language=en

Comment: So, your query is fine this time, just try zooming out a little bit (try "zoom=7"). I see results when zoom is <= 9. Also, you can always use "layer=basic" so see if you're zoomed in too much. "Basic" starts to show some water bodies even at the zoom level you're currently using.

Comment: You were right! Zoomed in too close. I'm not seeing my `path` on the map no matter the zoom though. Tried adding some `lw` and `lc` to make it stand out, but no go. Have you had success with showing `path`'s on the map?

Comment: As a quick follow up to the last comment here... there is a bug in the Azure Maps `path` API function. Being worked on at the moment...https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21449#issuecomment-453076094